# menu nav con flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

estoy iniciandome a usar flexbox, pero no hay manera de que consiga ajustar bien y nivelar los enlaces del menu de navegación, quedandose apegotonados los li, aún intentandole darles un justify content a los enlaces. Estoy algo confundido dado que he separado inclusive en dos contenedores tanto el titulo como los enlaces y no tengo manera de reajustarlo como quiero. Adjunto el html y scss que estoy construyendo

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 5px;

  .titulo {
    align-self: flex-start;
  }

  .enlaces {
    ul {
        display: flex;
        
      li {
        display: flex;
        list-style: none;
      }
      a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="titulo">
    <p>Nombre titulo</p>
  </div>
  <div class="enlaces">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Carrera</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Certificaciones</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tecnologias</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay algunas cosas que sobran en el código CSS, pero básicamente, para que los elementos de un flexbox no queden pegados entre sí, puedes usar la propiedad `gap`. Te adjunto cómo quedaría el código con algunos otros estilos comentados;

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center; /* Alinea los elementos del flexbox sobre el eje horizontal */
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 5px;
}

nav .titulo {
  /*align-self: flex-start;*/ /* Eliminada: usando justify-content: space-between en el flexbox, esta línea es innecesaria */
}

nav .enlaces ul {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px; /* Añade una separación entre cada uno de los elementos includios en el flexbox */
  margin: 0; /* Elimina el margen que por defecto incluye el ul */
  padding: 0; /* Elimina el margen que por defecto incluye el ul */
}

nav .enlaces ul li {
  /*display: flex;*/ /* Eliminada: esta línea es innecesaria, no tienes que ordenar ni distribuir ningún elemento dentro del li, que solo incluye un enlace */
  list-style: none;
}

nav .enlaces ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="titulo">
    <p>Nombre titulo</p>
  </div>
  <div class="enlaces">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Carrera</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Certificaciones</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tecnologias</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por la solución y explicación, me sirve de mucho!